# .htacces redirect to base url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect everything after a url back to it's main page.
for example: www.site.nl/subject/one    should redirect to www.site.nl/subject/    not matter whats after the slash. So even www.site.nl/subject/dasfa34q243aew  should go back to /subject.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `RedirectMatch` directive from mod_alias ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)) this should be pretty simple:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/subject/.+ http://example.com/subject/
```

Or even:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/([^/]+)/.+ http://example.com/$1/
```